# Is there a way to just copy the value from one path to another path via a Pass task in Step Functions (or something similarly simple)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have some complex state being used in my step function, and at one point, I just want to copy the value from one part of the state into another part of state without having to deal with it in a Lambda.

Simplified example:

```json
{
    "SomeStatus": {
         "Payload": {
              "attributeA": "blah"
              "attributeB": "blah2"
              "somethingImportant": 3
         }
    }
    "OperationOutput": {
         "Payload": {
              ... a bunch of attributes
              "somethingImportant": 6
         }
    }
```

And for my use case, I just want to copy the value of "somethingImportant" from "OperationOutput" to "SomeStatus", and so far I can't Pass it to work without wiping out the other attributes within "Payload". For example, I tried:

```js
  const copyValuePass = new StepFunctions.Pass(scope, 'CopyValuePass', {
    result: StepFunctions.Result.fromObject({
      SomethingImportant: StepFunctions.JsonPath.numberAt('$.OperationOutput.Payload.SomethingImportant'),
    }),
    // FIXME - this replaces the payload and gets rid of the attributes? 
    resultPath: '$.Input.Payload',
  })
```

Note: I've also run into issues with

`StepFunctions.JsonPath.numberAt('$.OperationOutput.Payload.SomethingImportant')` just placing the string path at `SomethingImportant: <>` instead of actually evaluating the value.

Is it possible to just copy over the one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of `SomeStatus.Payload.somethingImportant` to `6` (equal to `OperationOutput.Payload.somethingImportant`), modify your Pass state:

```js
parameters: {
    "Payload.$": "States.JsonMerge($.SomeStatus.Payload, States.StringToJson(States.Format('\\{\"somethingImportant\":\"{}\"\\}',$.OperationOutput.Payload.somethingImportant)), false)"
},
resultPath: "$.SomeStatus",
```

The nasty-looking `JsonMerge` intrinsic function performs a (shallow) merge of two objects:  `SomeStatus.Payload` and `OperationOutput.Payload.somethingImportant`.  The second object's values take precendence in the merge.  In order to squeeze the entire operation into a single Pass state, we hand-craft the second object using the `StringToJson` and `Format` intrinsic functions.

Notes:

1. The solution assumes `Payload` is the only key you need under `SomeStatus`, as in the OP.  `SomeStatus.Payload` is retained. Other keys (`SomeStatus.Foo`) will be discarded.
2. The Pass state's `result` key does not permit JSONPath substitutions.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot! If there are existing keys besides Payload under SomeStatus, would they be retained?

Comment: @CustardBun Glad to help.  No, only the `Payload` key is retained.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I think it'll suit my use case! But we might need to keep other attributes under Input along with Payload later. Would that be significantly more difficult?

Comment: @CustardBun A generizable solution will become much easier once `JsonMerge` supports deep merges (`true` in the 3rd arg).  Today only shallow merges are implemented.